# How does realtime text analysis happen

Tags: architecture, text-analysis

I have been doing some reading on this topic but am not able to find the right information, we have been using services like Twitter Streaming, Datasift and other data push service. What I wanted to understand how do the following services work,

1. The number of tweets received per second is very high.
2. A number of people connect specify the keywords they want to receive tweets for, these can be complex boolean queries.
3. realtime checking of all tweets against all these boolean queries and then streaming the data to the right connection.

Any pointer towards the kind of architecture being used would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i think you first need to understand the magnitude and resources of the services like twitter you are trying to create an understanding of!! The performance can be handled by managing taking care of both below mentioned fronts.

1. Imagine multi-tiered eco-system with load balancers, multiple web-servers and large data centres with distributed caching!!
2. irrespective of the complexity of algorithm performance can be managed by making algorithms multi-threaded!!

If you really want to understand try reading map-reduce, hadoop etc to get an idea